# Два условия при использовании IF Modx Revo

Tags: modx, revo

У меня есть такой код

```
[[*lock:is=`1`:then=`Locked`:else=`Open`]]
```

Мне нужно использовать еще одно условие, примерно так:

```
[[*lock:is=`1`&&+modx.user.id:is=`0`:then=`Locked`:else=`Open`]]
```

Только так не срабатывает. Как правильно написать условие AND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно через `:and:if` *([подробнее про модификаторы](https://docs.modx.pro/system/the-basics/filters-input-and-output))*

Стало быть так:

```
[[*lock:is=`1`:and:if=`[[+modx.user.id]]`:is=`0`:then=`Locked`:else=`Open`]]
```

---

При использовании [шаблонизатора Fenom](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/parser#%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-Fenom) условие будет выглядеть так:

```
{if $_modx->resource.lock == 1 and $_modx->user.id == 0}
    Locked
{else}
    Open
{/if}
```

Comment: не срабатывает, работает даже тогда, когда modx.user.id = 0

Comment: и я встречаю такие записи [\*lock\*] - это какой то новый вариант записи?

Comment: `[*lock*]` - это для modx редакции Evo такой синтаксис. Запись выше  по идеи должно вывести `Locked` если tv lock = 1 и пользователь не авторизирован. Сейчас проверил - всё вывело как надо. Попробуйте отдельно два условия проверить и только потом объедините в одно.